# Authentication Error on Select Android Devices

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

We are running MobileFirst Consumer Edition 7.0  We have a Liberty Server.
A majority of our users are able to successfully authenticate using our Mobile App with a AD Login.

A few users have reported that the log in hangs. Some other relevant information:  the users who have experienced this issue are using Android 5.0.2.  I can log in as them on other versions of Android without any problem. (I personally haven't been able to duplicate this).  When they log in, I am seeing this error in the logs when the login hangs.   What could be the issue?  If you need additional logs or a copy of the code, I can supply that via email. I just do not wish to disclose full logs here.

```
{
    "message": "Session ended for user \u0027REMOVED\u0027",
    "level": "INFO",
    "source": "server",
    "threadId": 52,
    "loggerName": "com.worklight.core.util.AuditBean",
    "timestamp": "25-08-15 10:50:45:320"
  },
  {
    "message": "Session ended for user \u0027REMOVED\u0027",
    "level": "INFO",
    "source": "server",
    "threadId": 52,
    "loggerName": "com.worklight.core.util.AuditBean",
    "timestamp": "25-08-15 10:42:27:321"
  },
  {
    "message": "FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: java.util.NoSuchElementException\ncom.worklight.gadgets.GadgetRuntimeException: java.util.NoSuchElementException\n\tat com.worklight.gadgets.api.GadgetAPIRequestCoder.decodeGadgetRequestInfoStandard(GadgetAPIRequestCoder.java:408)\n\tat com.worklight.gadgets.api.GadgetAPIRequestCoder.decodeGadgetRequestInfo(GadgetAPIRequestCoder.java:236)\n\tat com.worklight.gadgets.utils.GadgetUtils.getApplicationEnvironmentFrom(GadgetUtils.java:225)\n\tat com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.isDeviceDisabled(AuthenticationFilter.java:535)\n\tat com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:186)\n\tat com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)\n\tat com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)\n\tat com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:975)\n\tat com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1097)\n\tat com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81)\n\tat com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:912)\n\tat com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)\n\tat com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:938)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)\nCaused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException\n\tat java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)\n\tat com.worklight.gadgets.api.GadgetAPIRequestCoder.decodeGadgetRequestInfoStandard(GadgetAPIRequestCoder.java:367)\n\t... 15 more\n [project MyGPCMobile]",
    "sourceClass": "com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter",
    "sourceMethodName": "doFilter",
    "throwable": {
      "message": "java.util.NoSuchElementException",
      "stacktrace": [
        "com.worklight.gadgets.api.GadgetAPIRequestCoder.decodeGadgetRequestInfoStandard(GadgetAPIRequestCoder.java:408)",
        "com.worklight.gadgets.api.GadgetAPIRequestCoder.decodeGadgetRequestInfo(GadgetAPIRequestCoder.java:236)",
        "com.worklight.gadgets.utils.GadgetUtils.getApplicationEnvironmentFrom(GadgetUtils.java:225)",
        "com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.isDeviceDisabled(AuthenticationFilter.java:535)",
        "com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:186)",
        "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)",
        "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)",
        "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:975)",
        "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1097)",
        "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81)",
        "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:912)",
        "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)",
        "com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:938)",
        "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)",
        "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)",
        "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)"
      ]
    },
    "level": "SEVERE",
    "source": "server",
    "threadId": 196547,
    "loggerName": "com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter",
    "timestamp": "25-08-15 10:40:07:590"
  },
  {
    "message": "Session started for user \u0027REMOVED\u0027",
    "level": "INFO",
    "source": "server",
    "threadId": 191685,
    "loggerName": "com.worklight.core.util.AuditBean",
    "timestamp": "25-08-15 10:39:43:905"
  },
  {
```

Comment: We are not observing this error. You can supply your project with reproduction steps for debugging.

Comment: Waiting to hear back from you.

Comment: Sorry, Idan. I have been out at some conferences. I will email you the project in  a moment with details.

Comment: Hi Julie, there has been no activity on this StackOverflow post in some time. Did you find an answer?

Comment: No, I sent Idan a link to the project and haven't heard back. I have left the company I was asking for,  however I still contact for them.  I would not be the primary contact for this anymore.

Comment: @JulieBeck, Yep, sorry for not getting back to you. Can you ask the new contact person to see if there has been any progress here or if they have opened a PMR (perhaps they should if they'd like to progress with this issue if not yet resolved). Let us know.